# Loop to load all existing HTML files into one content

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I load all html files in a folder into a content? I have about 125 html files in a folder `src` and need to load them in a content called `.content`.

```
$(".content").load("src/1.html");
```

is this doable on client side using JavaScript?

Comment: Use a loop. On a side note, why are you loading 125 HTML files?

Comment: but this will overwrite the next file on existing file! am I right?

Answer (score -1):

I belive you need to use PHP to get the numbers of files on a specific folder on your root directory.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

If you read this, you will be able to get the folder array by using PHP and they you can use JS or JQuery to do rest.